# What is wrong with my Leibniz function (Python)?

Tags: python, function

as a newbie I'm trying to do a Leibniz pi approximation function. I think I've done it, but my function returns nothing. When I try my code without function it works. So it looks like I'm making a basic mistake here.

Can you tell me what's wrong with this function?

```
def myPi(iters):
    Pi = 0.0
    a = 1
    b = 1

    for n in range(iters):
        Pi += a / b
        a *= -1
        b += 2

    Pi *= 4
    return Pi

myPi(100000)
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/izshbH.

Comment: You aren't printing the result

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Using Python 3.x. I've tried the code by taking it out of the function (by adding a print() ofc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all answers friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the script as a module/script, Python does not automatically print unassigned non-None return values, as it does in REPL mode.

Change your last line to

```
print(myPi(100000))
```

OR

```
pi = myPi(100000)
print(pi)
```

Comment: I know I'm late, but I forgot to thank you for the answer, thanks alot!